# Cant RDP into server 2012 after VPN role added

Tags: windows, vpn, rdp, remote

Hi I installed the VPN role whilst connected to my remote Windows 2012 server via RDP. As soon as the service started my RDP session was ended and I can no longer reconnect. I also cannot connect via VPN. (Says that connection is denied because the username & password combination aren't recognised)

I can't immediately get access to the server to sort the issue on location. Is there anything I can do remotely?

Comment: Always buy servers with remote management cards (most have them anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launched the VPN, that would normally take over the network thus changing network configuration. That might have been the cause why RDP was disconnected.

Since you cannot connect to your VPN or RDP, unless you can access it via terminal, I don't think you have other options.

Comment: That would explain why Plex and email are no longer accessible also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rharris118 If you want to fix this remotely, if someone else can physically access your server, you have them install other remote access applications like TeamViewer. You can also mark this question as answered if your already satisfied with the answer. Best of luck.